# Realm - Object mapping and persist AnyObject type

Tags: ios, json, swift, realm

I'm building an app which both schemas are the same (DB & LocalDB).

This is great cause with one line of code Realm is parsing the JSON I get from the server.

```
if let JSON = response.result.value {
    let realm = try! Realm()

    do {
        try realm.write {
            realm.create(EMApplication.self, value:JSON, update: true)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Something went wrong!")
    }                   
}
```

The only problem is that Realm is asking to specifically provide a type to each property I set, but I have at least one property that I would like to use as `AnyObject` type:

```
class EMAnswer: Object {
    var id = RealmOptional<Int>()

    dynamic var name: String?

    var value: AnyObject?

    var staus: Status?
    var answerType: AnswerType?
}
```

My wish is to find a way for Realm to understand that `value` could by any type and parse it accordingly. Or do I need to take another path for parsing the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to put `AnyObject` properties into a Realm `Object` model subclass. It must either be one of the supported primitive types, a single Realm `Object`, or a `List` of Realm `Object` objects.

If the object is coming down as JSON, the easiest thing to do here is to maybe make `value` a `String` property, so you can save the data from JSON in its raw state. You can then later examine the value of `value` and work out what its type is from there.